# I have a tpl.php file. How can i check variable is set and print the value if the variable is set

Tags: theming

I am using in this way. Please correct me if i am wrong

I want the output as "(variable_value)"

`<?php if isset(variable_get('variable_name'))?>{
(<?php print t(variable_get('variable_name'));?>)}:`

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! How to print the value returned from a function between parenthesis is a plain PHP question that involves concatenating strings: `<?php print '(' . t(variable_get('variable_name')) . ')'; ?>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your variable is a string:

```
<?php if(isset($variable)): ?>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <?php print $variable; ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

With variable_get() and brackets:

```
<?php if isset(variable_get('variable_name')): ?>
  "<?php print t(variable_get('variable_name')); ?>"
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I want the value to be printed in brackets i.e (variable_value)

Comment: Last edit with only brackets

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if isset(variable_get('variable_name')): ?>
 <?php print t('('. variable_get('variable_name') . ')'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```